# Setting up a display environment variable for a remote unix system

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, x11-forwarding

Trying to get some graphical network simulator (ns2) code to display from my university's unix system. My local OS is Ubuntu 10 and I am accessing the unix system through PuTTY SSH client. When some prewritten code is executed, the following error prompt occurs:

```
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

What can be done to get remotely executed code to display on my system? I am a total novice with unix and my attempts at redefining the $DISPLAY env var were spectacular failures. Thanks. Appreciated.

Comment: You are using *PuTTY* on Linux? Sure there is a Linux version, but still... In any case you need to set-up X forwarding in PuTTY - or just use `ssh -X` in a terminal...

Comment: when I try to connect through my local unix terminal (via ssh cornell.unix.edu), it automatically sets my remote login name as my ubuntu name, which aren't the same. I don't know how to correct that besides creating a new ubuntu account.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do:

```
$ ssh -X username@cornell.unix.edu
```

This should launch `ssh` with X forwarding enabled, when run from a terminal emulator like Xterm, gnome-terminal and the like. `username` should be your account name on the remote computer, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Enable X forwarding in PuTTY. Option is in Connection/SSH/Tunnels.